# I am unable to submit questions and answers from Android App

Tags: bug, android-app

I am unable to submit questions and answers from Android App version 1.0.43 running on Android 4.3 (Samsung Galaxy SIII)

- My StackOverflow reputation at the time of this posting is only 16 if that has any impact.
- My Meta.StackExchange reputation at the time of this posting is only 1, again, if that has any impact.

I can post questions and answers from my PC.

My experience with asking a question is:

- I choose a site (Meta Stack Exchange)
- Type a Subject
- Compose question (> 160 characters)
- Choose a tag (android-app)
- Hit Preview - All displays well.
- Hit SUBMIT - The SUBMIT button changes to orange for the duration of the press, but nothing else happens.
- Hit the cross in the top left corner and the question closes.
- Go to create a new question, and I get a dialog asking if I want to resume or discard a draft. Clicking resume displays my un-posted question.

My experience with submitting an answer is:

- Click "View 0 Answers"
- Click "Add an answer"
- I compose my answer.
- I press "Preview" - Nothing appears to happen. No spinning wheel, nothing. (Actually, the preview button changes to orange from blue).
- I press "Submit" and the same result, except the submit button changes colour.

No question or answer is posted to the site.

Comment: Thanks for the report! You should at the *very least* be getting a error message, I'm sorry for the bad state. I'll take a look ASAP.

Comment: I've had 20 minutes spare time, so I installed a logcat, and attempt to reproduce my error to add some info. My post was successful, so I can't provide a logcat :-( I hope a change was made at the back end, cause the only difference is that the post that worked was sent on a 3g network the failed one was on a wifi connection. I will test again when i get wifi.

Comment: I think one letter is missing: "Samsun"

Comment: @I.T.Navigate let me know if it happens again on WiFi, I looked at all your API calls and none of them had any bad state (but granted we don't save POST data so all I could see is that a `200` was returned), I'm going to take a look at if we're just not displaying error messages in the app correctly, in case the API was returning something valuable.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi is there a sandbox i can test posting, or shall I test by answering this question? I got in trouble with my last test as it actually worked and threatened with account deletion.

Comment: @I.T.Navigate Yes, but it might overload your phone: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi Can't find the answer button :-(

Comment: @I.T.Navigate Yeah I figured, that post is our worst-case scenario in-app. Try posting an answer on here, then deleting it if it works.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi That worked, but how fo i delete it? I did get an auto update today.

Comment: @I.T.Navigate Hit the three dots next to it's timestamp and hit "Delete". I wonder what was causing this then...

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi Create another sandbox for the app, maybe?

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi I only have share edit and flag.

Comment: @I.T.Navigate Another bug! I deleted it :)

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi Ta. It's not a bug, it's a feature. :-)